# How do I open dev tools if 'oncontextmenu' event and ctrl+shift+i don't work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website that has implemented kind of dev tools blocking stuff.

> They disabled `oncontextmenu`  event setting it to `return false` and it doesn't show up at all.

> And they also blocked `CTRL`, `SHIFT` and `I` key events so nobody can access the dev tools.

How do I access the dev tools ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the *address bar* of your browser so that the page's listeners don't get fired when you type. Then you'll be able to use the default shortcuts like control-shift-I.